# Azure Table Storage insert with C# not inserting into table

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am new to Azure Table Storage, and followed a number of tutorials but cannot get any code to work  to insert data into the table. I actually populated the tables for now using Azure Storage Explorer by importing the csv files that have the data. I can retrieve the data from those tables using the following code.

```
public async Task<CurrencyEntity> GetCurrencyDataForDate(string currency, string date)
    {
        //ensure variables match key formats
        currency = currency.ToUpper();
        //var stringDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        
        var table = GetCloudTable(CcdConn, TableName);
        var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<CurrencyEntity>(currency, date);
        var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);

        var dto =  result?.Result as CurrencyEntity;
        return dto;
    }
```

Where CurrencyEntity is

```
public class CurrencyEntity : TableEntity
{
    public CurrencyEntity() { }
    public CurrencyEntity(string currency, string date)
    {
        Currency = currency;
        Date = date;

        PartitionKey = currency;
        RowKey = date;
    }
    public CurrencyEntity(string currency, string date, string close)
    {
        Currency = currency;
        Date = date;
        Close = close;

        PartitionKey = currency;
        RowKey = date;
    }

    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Close { get; set; }
    
}
```

But this method, although running thru to completion and returning a CurrencyEntity does not

```
 public async Task<CurrencyEntity> InsertNewCurrencyEntityAsync(CurrencyEntity currencyEntity)
    {
        //ensure values have proper format
        currencyEntity.Currency = currencyEntity.Currency.ToUpper();
        var parts = currencyEntity.Date.Split("-");
        if (parts.Length != 3) return null;
        if (parts[0].Length != 4 || parts[1].Length != 2 || parts[2].Length != 2) return null;

        TableResult result;
        var insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(currencyEntity);
        var table = GetCloudTable(CcdConn, TableName);
        // Execute the operation.
        try
        {
            result = await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOperation);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Upserts require a valid PartitionKey') The details are: 
            var message = $"{e.Message} The details are: {e.InnerException}";
            throw;
        }
        //var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOperation);
        var newCurrency = (CurrencyEntity)result.Result;

        return newCurrency;

    }
```

It returns newCurrency which looks like this

[image]

The incorrect Timestamp property gives some indication of failure even though there is no exception.
When retrieving this data it returns null (it wasn't inserted)

Comment: this seems similar to what you want to do, only difference i notice is you dont get the table reference name. https://serversncode.com/dotnet-c-sharp-with-azure-table-storage-inserting-retrieving-records/

Comment: the table reference name is the TableName variable in the call

Comment: using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table; but the Azure.Storage.Table sdk did not work for inserting or retrieving... I can retrieve now, I just cant insert. This is an Azure Storage Table.

Comment: @dinotom, do you mind sharing the real value of `currencyEntity` you passed into `InsertNewCurrencyEntityAsync` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to that you are actually using `InsertOrMerge` method instead of `Insert` method in `InsertNewCurrencyEntityAsync(CurrencyEntity currencyEntity)` function.

Please use `Insert` method if you want to insert a new record, like below:

```
public async Task<CurrencyEntity> InsertNewCurrencyEntityAsync(CurrencyEntity currencyEntity)
{

   //other code

    TableResult result;

    //var insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(currencyEntity);

    //use the Insert method if you want to add a new record.
    var insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.Insert(currencyEntity);

    var table = GetCloudTable(CcdConn, TableName);

   
  //other code

 }
```

Comment: @dinotom, are there any errors? and it's better to provide the detailed value you're inserted.

Comment: You can also open fiddler when running this code, and see if there is a related `http Post request` for the insert operation.

Comment: @dinotom, hello, I want to know if are there any updates for this issue?

Comment: I had shoulder surgery so havent been working. now that im up to it ill review this later today

Comment: I found the issue, when I was testing it, I was using lowercase currency string which was not being converted to upper case for the entity search. I fixed that in the CurrencyEntity constructor. All good now.